# Calculate complex Logarithm

Tags: complex-analysis, logarithms

[image]

Log(1) = 0 for both Domains. 
I have problems to determine log(e). I hope you can help me out here.

EDIT: I have to determine log(e) for both simply connected regions 1) and 2) which you can see in the picture above.

Comment: @parsiad These are two simply connected regions with a branch of Log defined on them such that $Log(1) = 0$.

Comment: Edited the original post. Thanks

Comment: Connect $1$ to $e$ with a contour through each domain, and integrate $1/z$ along it. Once you have chosen the contour, you can forget the funny-looking domains and replace the contour with an easier one that is homotopic to it within $\mathbb C\setminus\{0\}$ ...

Comment: @Situ: retracted close vote after edit

Comment: Do you mean the contour integral of the logarithm?  Because the logarithm of $e$ will always be $1$...